# Finish some activities from stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

From my `MainActivity` I launch a series of chooser activities. Once user is done with those activities I want to remove them from stack.
e.g. if stack looks like this:

`MainActivity`->`ChooserActivityA`->`ChooserActivityB`->`ChooserActivityC`

And user presses a button on `ChooserActivityC` to launch `SomeActivity` then I want stack to be:

`MainActivity`->`SomeActivity`.

Is there a way to achieve this? Please note that user should be able to go back from `ChooserActivityC` to `ChooserActivityB` so finishing activities before launching next one is not an option.

I have tried creating a new task when launching `ChooseActivityA` using `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and I was thinking of just finishing the whole task once `SomeActivity` is launched using `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` but that seems to finish `MainActivity` too. And reason seems to be that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` didn't created a new task in first place.

I would love any help to achieve this in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use one host Activity as a navigation controller and many Fragments.

There is a way to investigate back stack with [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29), but it's deprecated.

Anyway, it could be too "hacky". Be simple, so a developer who will read the code don't want to kill you =)

Comment: Yes that is an option and in fact  I am already doing this in other parts of the app with view pager+fragments. 
But I want to find out if there is a way to do this with activities.